# React/TypeScript `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.` when trying to redirect on timeout

Tags: reactjs, typescript, timeout, setstate

I have a project that I'm trying to get to redirect from page 1 to 2 etc. dynamically. This has worked for me previously, but recently I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

After seeing this message this morning, and multiple SO pages saying NOT to call `setState` in `render`, I have moved my `setTimeout` call into `componentDidMount`.

So far I've tried 
 - calling a function that changes `this.props.pageWillChange` property, then in render I return a  object based on that condition
 - returning a  object pending condition set in an inline if statement in render
 - turning pageWillChange into a local prop, rather than one that is inherited by the class (I quite like this option, as the state of this will be the same for every new version of this component)

Many more things, but these felt like they would work. Anyone able to help?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { GridList, GridListTile } from "@material-ui/core"

import "../assets/scss/tile.scss"
import Request from "../config.json"
import DataTile from "./DiagnosticDataTile"
import { IDiagnosticResultData } from "../interfaces/IDiagnosticResultData"
import { Redirect } from "react-router"

interface IProps {
  category: string
  redirect: string
}

interface IPageState {
  result: IDiagnosticResultData[]
  pageWillChange: boolean
}

class Dashboard extends Component<IProps, IPageState> {
  _isMounted = false
  changeTimeInMinutes = 0.25
  willRedirect: NodeJS.Timeout

  constructor(props: Readonly<IProps>, state: IPageState) {
    super(props)
    this.state = state
    console.log(window.location)
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this._isMounted = true
    this.ChangePageAfter(this.changeTimeInMinutes)

    axios
      .get(Request.url)
      .then(response => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({ result: response.data })
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this._isMounted = false
    clearTimeout(this.willRedirect)
  }

  ChangePageAfter(minutes: number): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ pageWillChange: true })
    }, minutes * 60000)
  }

  render() {
    var data = this.state.result
    //this waits for the state to be loaded
    if (!data) {
      return null
    }

    data = data.filter(x => x.categories.includes(this.props.category))

    return (
      <GridList
        cols={this.NoOfColumns(data)}
        cellHeight={this.GetCellHeight(data)}
        className="tileList"
      >
        {this.state.pageWillChange ? <Redirect to={this.props.redirect} /> : null}
        {data.map((tileObj, i) => (
          <GridListTile
            key={i}
            className="tile"
          >
            <DataTile data={tileObj} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard
```

(very new with React and TypeScript, and my first SO post woo!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, also couple of points:

- No need for `_isMounted` field. Code in 'componentDidMount' always runs after it's mounted.
- No need to set state in constructor. Actually there is no need for constructor anymore.
- I can't see much point of `clearTimeout` in `componentWillUnmount` mount. It's never asigned to timeout.

About routing. U can use 'withRouter' high order function to change route programmatically in `changePageAfter` method.

Hope this helps!

```
import axios from "axios"
import { GridList, GridListTile } from "@material-ui/core"

import "../assets/scss/tile.scss"
import Request from "../config.json"
import DataTile from "./DiagnosticDataTile"
import { IDiagnosticResultData } from "../interfaces/IDiagnosticResultData"
import { Redirect, RouteComponentProp } from "react-router"

interface PropsPassed {
  category: string
  redirect: string
}

type Props = PropsPassed & RouteComponentProp

interface IPageState {
  result: IDiagnosticResultData[]
  pageWillChange: boolean
}

class Dashboard extends Component<Props, IPageState> {
  changeTimeInMinutes = 0.25
  willRedirect: NodeJS.Timeout

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.ChangePageAfter(this.changeTimeInMinutes)

    axios
      .get(Request.url)
      .then(response => {   
          this.setState({ result: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  changePageAfter(minutes: number): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/somepage',
  });
    }, minutes * 60000)
  }

  render() {
    var data = this.state.result
    //this waits for the state to be loaded
    if (!data) {
      return null
    }

    data = data.filter(x => x.categories.includes(this.props.category))

    return (
      <GridList
        cols={this.NoOfColumns(data)}
        cellHeight={this.GetCellHeight(data)}
        className="tileList"
      >
        {data.map((tileObj, i) => (
          <GridListTile
            key={i}
            className="tile"
          >
            <DataTile data={tileObj} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard)
```

Comment: Ah this is great. I'd seen the `this.prop.history.push` approach before but I didn't know you could import extra props in from elsewhere.

This is now performing the redirects, but with some bugs that affect some animations I threw in a while ago. Definitely a good place for me to continue working from!